# Box shadow using css to multiple sides

Tags: html, css

I am  trying to show shadow of my container div by doing this.

```
div {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
background-color: yellow;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}
```

But this show shadow to right and bottom. I want to control the shadow. Can anyone guide me how can i show shadow to only one single side i-e right/left or top/bottom. Working Jsfiddle will help me to understand this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can create like following:

```
div {
width: 300px;
height: 100px;
background-color: yellow;
box-shadow: inset 10px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.81);
}
```

Above will show left side shadow.
 Also for right side shadow use:

```
box-shadow: inset -10px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.81);
```

Check [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/avhm9sdo/) here.

You can use Shadow Generator : [Link](http://www.cssmatic.com/box-shadow)

Answer (score 0):

Please Try this [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nw9hea4y/1/)

i hope i may helpfull for you

```
.box
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
float:left;
width:200px;
height:100px;
background:#ccc;
margin-left:20px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 41px 0px 50px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.32);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 41px 0px 50px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.32);
 box-shadow: inset 41px 0px 50px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.32);
 }
```